# How to upgrade Mongodb to support TLSv1.3.?

Tags: mongodb, openssl, centos7, tls1.2, tls1.3

I am using MongoDB 3.6 with MongoDB Java Driver 3.9 & OpenJDK 11 with OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips on Centos 7 operating system.

**What will be the minimal change required to support TLSv1.3?
Do we have any matrice for the TLS version, MongoDB, Driver, and Java?**

Going through MongoDB Doc below are some option to enable TLS/SSL.

**For MongoDb 3.6:**
mongo --ssl --sslPEMKeyFile  --sslCAFile   --authenticationDatabase '$external' --authenticationMechanism MONGODB-X509

--tlsDisabledProtocols arg : Comma separated list of TLS protocols
to disable [TLS1_0,TLS1_1,TLS1_2]

**For MongoDb 4.2:**
mongo --tls --tlsCertificateKeyFile  --tlsCAFile   --authenticationDatabase '$external' --authenticationMechanism MONGODB-X509

--tlsDisabledProtocols arg : Comma separated list of TLS protocols
to disable [TLS1_0,TLS1_1,TLS1_2]

*It Will need Driver Upgrade*

Trying To force Application to use a specific version of TLS
-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2 : Handshake Succesful
-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.3 : (HANDSHAKE_FAILURE): Couldn't kickstart handshaking

[Short Note in Mongodb 4.4 release notes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.4/index.html)
TLS 1.3 Support
On CentOS 8 and RHEL 8, MongoDB 4.4 (as well as versions 4.2, 4.0, and 3.6) support TLS1.3.

**Can anybody suggest me what all technology stack need to be upgraded for minimal impact?**
Appreciate your help!!

Comment: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-37135 seems helpful.

Comment: If we conclude this link, Is it suggesting us to upgrade OpenSSL from 1.0.1e to 1.1.1?

Comment: I would say start with that.

Answer (score 0):

**Ensure that your OpenSSL library is updated to version 1.1.1a or a higher version.**